# Can an rvalue vector be allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology here, but say I have a function that returns a vector:

```
std::vector<int> func()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(100,1);
    return vec;
}
```

And when I call this function I want to allocate the vector on the heap. Can I do this?

I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> vec(new std::vector<int>);
vec->swap(func());
```

Is there a way of doing this that is less convoluted, without changing `func()`?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do.  A `vector<T>`'s *contents* (the actual array of `T` it contains) will be allocated on the heap anyway, unless you specify otherwise by providing a special allocator (`std::vector<int, special_allocator<int> >`).

Comment: Do **not** use `std::move` here, it prevents optimisations.

Comment: Maybe you just want `std::vector<int>* func() { return new std::vector<int>(100, 1); }`?  But using raw pointers to standard containers is nearly always a bad idea -- what are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a `std::unique_ptr` instead of a `shared_ptr`, since you don't need the reference counting of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I want to keep a shared pointer to the vector to keep it alive after the function exits, but I don't want to return a pointer from a function...

Comment: @KonradRudolph why is that? Isn't that what the compiler would do anyway?

Comment: Then the function prototype should be `shared_ptr<vector<int> > func()`.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz I think you are contradicting yourself. You want a pointer, but you don't want a pointer. Sounds weird to me.

Comment: I think the relevant question here is: Will this provide any performance benefit over simply returning a `std::vector`?. On the topic of avoiding `std::move`: If you write that, the compiler can't do return-value optimization.

Comment: I'm not sure if you realize just how little data is on the activation stack for most implementations of a vector (or maybe you do). And RVO should elide any copy concerns if you squelch that move. And you seriously need to clarify what "keep alive" means.

Comment: @Kirinyale I don't want a pointer, but in certain builds I want to keep the vector alive after the scope has exited, so this seems like the only really sensible solution, other than just returning a smart pointer all the time, which I am trying to avoid since it's not necessary for those builds.

Comment: @WhozCraig I probably don't...

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: If you simply return the vector, it will stay alive _iff_ the function result is evaluated, and until the function result has been evaluated.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz The only way to make something live outside of its scope is to allocate it on the heap. To allocate something on the heap, you always use a pointer (even with a placement new). Of course, you can still change the scope of your vector by copying it into some object that lives longer. Or accept a reference as a function argument and construct the vector there (then its lifetime depends on whoever created the object originally).

Comment: If *you* implemented a dynamic vector class how would *you* do it? A base typed-pointer that references heap-managed memory, a capacity `size_t`, and a occupied `size_t` ? If you think most implementations follow that same forethought, you'd be right. You're looking at between 16 and 24 bytes of stack data, the rest by default is heap managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only better way i can think of is not use `std::move` since the compiler automatically does RVO

The second expression can be shortened a bit :

```
std::vector<int>* vec2 = new std::vector<int>( f() );
```

And just like what other says, allocating vector on the heap isn't really neccessary

Answer (score 2):

Just try to remove that `std::move`, it's a specific compiler exception to avoid you put a `std::move` and let the compiler to do the rest.

```
std::vector<int> func()
{
    std::vector<int> vec(100,1);
    return vec; // NOT: return std::move(vec);
}
```

Why?

Because, the automatic object `vec` is going to destroy after executing `return` and it will be behave as same as a rvalue in this case. Then compiler will move it. Putting `std::move` will annoy the compiler to NRVO.

That simple returning the vector is optimized and don't worry about the performance.

Comment: “When you say it's wrong, then it's wrong.” – That’s not a sentiment I generally want to encourage. :-p Unfortunately I can’t be bothered now to find proof in the standard; however, here’s an example demonstrating that it’s at least true in *some* circumstances: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8201a43740ed7c51

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Compiling your code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3804ac0838f9ae9f) with `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable eliding, I think it shows, for `f()` compiler tries to move, isn't it? Then, we can conclude the compiler moves the object when returning. It's just my guess, maybe my conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes, if it cannot elide the the copy, the constructor will instead try to move on return. Unfortunately my initial comment got deleted (?! – wasn’t by me!) so I cannot check any more what exactly I’d written.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know what you're doing, how much can you optimize away from the stack without any trade-offs or from the heap if you want more fragments in your system memory ? If you have millions of records you need to allocate on "your heap", the first thing comes to my mind is your chance to get it corrupted with operations possible existing in your code is high. Second, heap size is limited then you need to re-implement your allocator to handle "how to deal with small memory and large data to be stored". 
If you insist on optimization strategy over heap management, then returning pointer to the vector seems promising

```
std::vector<int*>* yourfunc()
{
    // do something
    return pVec;
}
```

then `new` method is applied but object deletion at the end is still required.

Comment: Apparently for both the vector *and* its elements ? not sure whats going on with the latter.

Comment: @ArmanSchwarz: Then, in C++11 just return it simply by `return vec;` and even in previous C++ version, there is RVO which avoids those redundant actions.

Comment: @MM. That's what I'm doing.

Comment: Oh you mean because of the `std::move`? I see why that was wrong, I've removed it now. It wasn't really the point of the question though.